# How can I catch a format error from strftime as an exception?

Tags: c++, error-handling, visual-studio-2013, strftime

I use `::strftime()` in a VS2013 C++ program. Is there a way to handle an `"invalid format"` error correctly, without the risk of stopping the whole program?

When I run code like the function below with a wrong format, say `"%Y- %- m-%d"`, it's "GAME OVER".  I get:

> "Debug Assertion Failed ... Invalid format directive"

and I can only stop the application (a unit-test-suite).

Is there a way to turn this into an exception, an `errno` code, etc so I can handle this situation properly?

Or, is there another function I should use?

Or, must I check the format-string *manually* before I call `strftime()`?

```
using namespace std;
string foo( string fmt ) // fmt: user supplied format - may be invalid
{
  if (fmt.empty()) return "";
  struct tm  myTm = ...; // get it some how
  size_t n = 0;
  size_t buflen = 2 * fmt.size();
  while (buflen < 100) {
    vector<char> buf( buflen, '\0' );
    try {
      n = ::strftime( buf.data(), buf.size(), fmt.c_str(), &myTm );
      if (n>0)
        return string( buf.data(), buf.data() + n );
      if ((n == 0) && (34 == errno)) {
        // 34 == "Result too large" (at least in VS2013)
        buflen *= 2; // try with larger buffer
        continue;
      }
      //   I NEVER REACH THIS POINT!  :-(
      throw runtime_error( "please check your format string!" );
    }
    catch (...) {
      //   I NEVER REACH THIS POINT!  :-(
      throw runtime_error( "please check your format string" );
    }
  }
  throw runtime_error( "max buffer size reached" );
}
```

Comment: `strftime` is a function from the C library, and as a C function it doesn't know anything about exceptions and can't throw one.

Comment: By the way, user-supplied formats is usually a very bad idea. It opens up your code for possible exploits.

Comment: I know, it's a C function. So I expected to get an errno or so. But I don't. :-(

Comment: It need not be an exception. All I want is to handle the bad-format error - but VS2013 forces me to stop the program (also in Release mode).

Comment: Why would you ever pass a user-supplied format string to `strftime`?  Are you expecting your users to type this in verbatim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`strftime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strftime-wcsftime-strftime-l-wcsftime-l?view=vs-2019) documentation says:

> This function validates its parameters. If strDest, format, or timeptr is a null pointer, or if the tm data structure addressed by timeptr is invalid (for example, if it contains out of range values for the time or date), or if the format string contains an invalid formatting code, the invalid parameter handler is invoked, as described in [Parameter Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/parameter-validation?view=vs-2019). If execution is allowed to continue, the function returns 0 and sets errno to EINVAL.

The [Parameter Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/parameter-validation?view=vs-2019) documentation says:

> **Invalid Parameter Handler Routine**
>
> When a C Runtime Library function detects an invalid parameter, it captures some information about the error, and then calls a macro that wraps an invalid parameter handler dispatch function, one of _invalid_parameter, _invalid_parameter_noinfo, or _invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn. The dispatch function called depends on whether your code is, respectively, a debug build, a retail build, or the error is not considered recoverable.
>
> In Debug builds, the invalid parameter macro usually raises a failed assertion and a debugger breakpoint before the dispatch function is called. When the code is executed, the assertion may be reported to the user in a dialog box that has "Abort", "Retry", and "Continue" or similar choices, depending on the operating system and runtime library version. These options allow the user to immediately terminate the program, to attach a debugger, or to let the existing code continue to run, which calls the dispatch function.
>
> The invalid parameter handler dispatch function in turn calls the currently assigned invalid parameter handler. By default, the invalid parameter calls _invoke_watson which causes the application to "crash," that is, terminate and generate a mini-dump. If enabled by the operating system, a dialog box asks the user if they want to load the crash dump to Microsoft for analysis.
>
> This behavior can be changed by using the functions [_set_invalid_parameter_handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-invalid-parameter-handler-set-thread-local-invalid-parameter-handler?view=vs-2019) or [_set_thread_local_invalid_parameter_handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-invalid-parameter-handler-set-thread-local-invalid-parameter-handler?view=vs-2019) to set the invalid parameter handler to your own function. If the function you specify does not terminate the application, control is returned to the function that received the invalid parameters. In the CRT, these functions will normally cease function execution, set errno to an error code, and return an error code. In many cases, the errno value and the return value are both EINVAL, indicating an invalid parameter. In some cases, a more specific error code is returned, such as EBADF for a bad file pointer passed in as a parameter. For more information on errno, see errno, _doserrno, _sys_errlist, and _sys_nerr.

Comment: This answer is nothing but copied documentation, which may as well be linked in a comment instead. Could you digest this a bit and explain, possibly with examples, with how OP can recover from formatting errors?

Comment: @alterigel The ability to read and understand documentation is a very important ability required for programmers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the "Parameter Validation" section.
This is MS specific, right?

Comment: I tried my own handler - working fine.
But I will probably use a handwritten format-check before calling :strftime

Comment: @ToniSchilling The C11 standard says this about `strftime`: "If a conversion specifier is not one of the above, the behavior is undefined." So every library implementer will have their own specific functionality.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk: OK, thanks again. I was looking for a statement like this, but I missed it. 
Knowing this now, I will definitely write my own format-string-checker.
Did not expect, such a simple and easy-to-handle thing like a wrong format is allowed to be undefined behavior by the standard.